# MySql - Concatenate/merge multiple columns into one column with hard codded titles

Tags: php, mysql

i should migrate multiple columns of text into one column (in another database). Now i know that it sounds complicated, but i will try my best to explain it.
There is a table in mysql database called "products_desriptions". In that table we have columns like: descriptionDosage, descriptionAction, descriptionIndications and so on. What i want to do is to merge these columns into one column called "productDescription". 
Here is an example of what i have done:

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT_WS('\ntest', action, Indications, staff, dosage) AS productDescription)
FROM 
   products_descriptions
WHERE 
   product_id = 123
```

So the the columns are being merged successfully.
The problem is that for each column there is a title in the frontpage, which is not being stored into the respective column. For example in the "dosage" column we have text like: "2xday, 14xweek" and so on. And on the frontpage what you can see is something like: 
"DOSAGE:
2xday, 14xweek" and so on.
So for each column there is a hard codded title like this one, which i don't know how to get. I mean what i want to do is: to merge columns and respectively for each column i want a title to the respective text.
I am working on php, so maybe it is not possible to be done only by mysql. Maybe i have to do it with php, but has anyone got any idea what exactly should i do?

Comment: can't you simply add the title to the concat? like `CONCAT_WS(....., staff, 'DOSAGE: ', dosage)...` - you'd then only have to cope with the `\n` in between...

Comment: yes, but there are multiple titles. Foreach column i have unique title

Comment: then just do the same for each column/title!?

Comment: overall I guess it would be better to normalize that data anyway...but it seems that you _have_ to do it that way unfortunately.

Comment: what do you mean by "normalize that data"? And thanks for the help, dude

Answer (score 1):

You can use `concat` function.

```
SELECT 
   CONCAT('\ntest', action, '\nIndictions:', Indications,'\nstaff:', staff,'\ndosage:', dosage) AS productDescription
FROM 
   products_descriptions
WHERE 
   product_id = 123
```

Comment: That's it. I didn't think it will be that simple. Thank you so much, dude! :)