# Mysql - Export multiple columns and import them into one column

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to export a database from a site (site 1) and import it to another database (site 2) with a different structure.

So what i am asking is this:

In the database of site 1 we are having a table called "products" and then we have a child table `products_descriptions` (which is connected with a foreign key with `products`). So in the child table we have different columns like `staff`, `dosage`, `indications` and so on.

Then we have site 2's database. We got a table called `products`. And in that table we have a column called `productDescription`.

So what i need to do is to export the `products_descriptions` table from site 1 and import it to the `productDescription` column in the `products` table from site 2.

This question is related  with the question i asked yesterday. Here is a link: [MySql - Concatenate/merge multiple columns into one column with hard codded titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51946963/mysql-concatenate-merge-multiple-columns-into-one-column-with-hard-codded-titl/51947146?noredirect=1#comment90844204_51947146)

But i don't think that's the right way of thinking.

So can anyone give any tip about the right approach in this situation?

Comment: i think you will find what you looking for by referring this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20284528/how-to-concat-two-columns-into-one-with-the-existing-column-name-in-mysql/20285571

Answer (score 0):

Right down php script to take one by one entry from the First Database table and insert in Second database appropriate table. You have to connect both database with Different connection link.